# Apache2 is getting restarted at 9 and 39 minutes after the hour

Tags: apache2, php

With php5.6 my apache2 server restarts an 9 and 39 minutes after the hour all the time. Doesn't matter if the server is doing anything or not.

I have investigated the issue and I think sessionclean is responsible. It seems there is a need to clean up old php session files and in php5.6 a new way of doing it was implemented. I see evidence supporting this statement in the system log. (dmesg)

Some of my applications run for hours. Some of them run for 10 to 15 minutes. These applications get terminated at 9 and 39 minutes past the hour. It is making me continue to run with php5.5.

Please help me to fix this. I am ok with periodically cleaning up old files. I suspect the sessionclean program will not successfully do its job if apache2 is running so apache2 is terminated and immediately restarted.

I have more information, such as logs and configuration files, that I can provide, if needed. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I set up another computer. Tis time I did not istall php 5.6 and php 7.1, just 7.1. Everything works fine with this computer.

Comment: Removed php everything and reinstalled. Back to it is being nasty. Going to remove php7.1.

Comment: System is running with php5.6 only. apache2 continues to die at 9 and 39 minutes after the hour.

Comment: Obviously, I don't know how to use this forum. I don't think anybody ever read this. If you have you can easy fix this issue by removing the cron job that starts sessionclean. I think there is a bug in sessionclean but what the heck. My jobs run to completion after removing the cron job. I typically power cycle by computer only on updates so eventually I'll see if I broke anything.